# passing a php array to a jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

I need to pass a php variable to a jquery function. the php variable is an array of unknown size. is there a way to pass each member of the array to be processed individually by the function?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you should use JSON to pass the php variable to jquery. its the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to print the array and parse that to receive a JS object.

I assume you use AJAX (directly printing into the javascript source is possible but ill-advised).

Your php script needs to print output directly:

```
print_r(json_encode($data_array));
```

And on the receiving end use $.parseJSON:

```
var data_array = $.parseJSON(ajax_result);
```

Comment: `echo` instead of `print_r` for passing it to a JS var/Ajax response btw.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté There is little difference in this case. print_r does not format the data in any way unless it is an object or an array. Also, you can rig print_r to return the value and use it in expressions, which is impossible for echo.